# react select with form hook form submit

Tags: reactjs

this works fine on form submit shows selected value when I add onChange event then on form submit it doesnot show selected value

```
<Controller name="CostCenterGrp" className="form-control" control={control} render={({ field, value}) => ( <ReactSelect {...field} isClearable options={costCenterHeads} value={value} /> )}`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add field.onchange inside the component to manual edit the value
field.onChange(event);

```
  <Controller
  render={({ field }) => <input onChange={event=>{
      handleSampleChange(event);
      field.onChange(event);
    }} />}
  name="sample"
  control={control}
/>
```

Comment: If working, give an upvote for the answer